# Xamarin.forms implement a custom back button options

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a custom navigation bar with a really ugly back button.  In order, I would like to have a polygon arrow with text in it (like a simple 5 sided flag that says back and I can change font/color/etc) or a rounded corner button with back in it.  What is the best way to achieve this or are there other ways?  I don’t know that I am good enough to tackle a custom renderer just yet, but it might be on the list.

What I have looked at is:

To get the arrow-> using a image that looks like what I want (don’t like for theming reasons and I might want to reference which page to go to)

To get the button -> using flexbutton but right now it is not supported in UWP.

What other options are out there?

Comment: Could you show an image of the end result ?

Comment: https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/gray-toolbar-5/512/tag-512.png

Comment: And sorry I couldn’t actually load the image, my reputation stinks.